# Responsive Full Screen Overlay Navigation Below Header

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I created a pen to accompany my question:

http://codepen.io/mtorosian/pen/tKGcF

HTML

```
<div id="header"><a href="#" id="trigger">Trigger</a></div>
<div id="overlay">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="nav">
    <tr>
        <td class="nav-box-1">Test</td>
        <td class="nav-box-2">Test</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="nav">
    <tr>
        <td class="nav-box-3">Test</td>
        <td class="nav-box-4">Test</td>
    </tr>
</table>    
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#header {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 20px 0;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
#overlay {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #000;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
}
#overlay.active{
    display: block;
}
.nav {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}
.nav td {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.nav-box-1 {
    background-color: red;
}
.nav-box-2 {
    background-color: blue;
}
.nav-box-3 {
    background-color: green;
}
.nav-box-4 {
    background-color: yellow;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .nav  {
        width: 100%;
        height: 50%;
    }
}
```

jQuery

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

var header = $('#header').outerHeight();

$( "#trigger" ).click(function() {
    $('#overlay').toggleClass('active');
    $('#overlay').css({'top' : header});
});
});
```

Trying to determine the best way to build out a full screen overlay that sits below the header of the website. On larger screens the 4 sections would take up 25% each of the screen while on smaller screens it would be stacked into a quad structure with two on top and two on bottom each taking up 50%. I feel like I have this working somewhat in the pen I created but wondering if this is the best way to tackle it. It feels a bit sloppy to me using tables for this layout. I started out with a div structure using display: table and display: table-cell but couldn't get the 50% height portion working on smaller screens like it is with using actual tables.

Comment: Don't use `tables` for designing your website.

Comment: How about using a grid system? A css grid, like this one: http://www.1140px.com/

Comment: Aaron, I'm not using tables for designing the entire website, just trying to determine how to do the overlay like it is shown in the codepen demo. Not sure how a grid would help with that either.

Answer (score 0):

To get `height: 100%` to work you need to set the parent elements (body, html, #overlay) to `height: 100%`

http://jsbin.com/quwisexodi/1/edit?html,css,js,output

I've used `calc(100% - 100px)` to set the height of `#main` since `#header` has a static pixel height. If we use `height:10%` on `#header` and `height:90%`, `calc()` is no longer necessary.